# Amazon S3 bucket name uniqueness and domain name

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a domain for example mydomain.com and a bucket on Amazon S3 that hosts my static website.

I want to link my domain to my bucket.

The bucket name should be same as my domain name:

> [The bucket must have the same name as your domain or subdomain. For example, if you want to use the subdomain acme.example.com, the name of the bucket must be acme.example.com.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html)

and bucket names are unique in Amazon S3:

> [The name must be unique across all existing bucket names in Amazon S3.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/CreatingABucket.html)

the problem is a bucket with my domain name already exists and its not mine.

Comment: Did you try Route 53 for the domain name ?

Comment: i created a hosted zone in route 53 and im trying to create a record set

Comment: just hit this exact same problem

Comment: @Dreamwalker i solved (ignored) this by using amazon cloud front, i have created a cloud front and added my bucket to it then used Route 53 to point my domain to cloud front

Comment: You should drop that in as a solution in here ;) and I was just thinking I could do that its OTT for my simple site but i'll try it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login into your AWS console, in the **services** menu under the **Networking & Content Delivery** group click on the **CloudFront**

in the CloudFront Distributions page click on the **Create Distribution** button

after creating click on its ID in the list to go to configuration page

in the **Origins and Origin Groups** tab click **Create Origin** buton and enter your bucket name in **Origin Domain Name** field and fill other boxes

now you can go to **Route 53** -> **hosted zones** and create a new hosted zone with your domain and create an A record like www.mydomain.com and point it to cloudFront